# What is the secret to surfing?

Tags: team-fortress-2, counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-source, source-engine

What's the trick to surfing? I've seen many surfing maps, yet I can barely complete any of them because I don't know how to surf.

Also, is surfing different in each of the source games you can play it on? For example, is CS:S's surfing mechanics different from CS:GO's surfing mechanics?  Is it the same thing on TF2?

Comment: The secret is don't press the forward or back keys.  Strafe toward the ramp but look where you're going.  It should feel similar to rocket jumping.

Comment: @tugs You can strafe in any direction, it depends on which way you are facing in relation to the ramp.

Comment: Catching an awesome wave dude!

Comment: This was pretty good: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfPut6AAAYo

Answer (score 4):

Always face towards and in the direction you wish to move (across the ramp.) Move left and right (strafing) and avoid pressing the forward or backward keys as they will often cause you to stop. Jumping or crouching is often not necessary.